# how to change prefix position in q-input in quasar framework

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm new to this so maybe its obvious but i cant find a way to change the position of prefix in quasar q-input and i mean only prefix position.
I have this

```
<q-input outlined v-model="number" prefix="$"> </q-input>
```

it shows : 34 $

i want it to be:  $ 34

i look the documentation in https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#custom-label
but i cant find a way to change the position of prefix.
i changed the direction but it didn't work, i should mention i have rtl= true in quasar config.

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
  <q-input outlined v-model="number" prefix="$">
  </q-input>
  
  <q-input outlined v-model="number" suffix="$">
  </q-input>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/vYzBpyw

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you have rtl=true, if you don't want to change that just try to use suffix. Not the prefix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).